# Cannot access 'androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultCaller'

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity, androidx

I'm using **androidx** for quite a while and my Android project compiles fine, however recently my Android Studio throws tons of red for all Activity classes

[image] because of

`cannot access 'androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultCaller' which is a supertype of ...`

I use

**AppCompatActivity** from `androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0`

My **build.gradle** has:

```
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.71'
    ...
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
```

And **gradle version** 
`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.4-all.zip`

My **gradle.properties**:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4608m
org.gradle.parallel=true

# Use kapt in parallel
kapt.use.worker.api=true

# Kapt compile avoidance
kapt.include.compile.classpath=false
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This happened because of Gradle when resolving dependency libraries versions upgraded `androidx.core:core` to version more than 1.2.0, probably to 1.3.0-beta01 or 1.3.0-rc01

`AppCompatActivity` extends `FragmentActivity`
that extends `ComponentActivity`
that extends `androidx.core.app.ComponentActivity`
that implements `ActivityResultCaller`
introduced in `androidx.activity:activity:1.2.0-alpha03` only.

To resolve this issue add this dependency to your **module** `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
      implementation "androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.2.0-alpha03"
}
```

Comment: I managed to fix it with some AS update, but then a new AS came, and the problem returned. Thx, this is the correct answer! :)

Answer (score 2):

In my case, turns out I had conflicting `androidx.activity:activity-ktx` gradle dependencies between my core/base and app module.

In addition to **ActivityResultCaller**, mine was throwing an issue with **ActivityResultRegistryOwner**.

For me, removing the dependency from the app module, pushing the core module dependency to `androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.2.0-alpha04` and bumping `implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.0` > `1.3.1` solved both issues.

I also have an `androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0-alpha01` dependency in core, which I kept, but it seems removing it has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I needed to remove `implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0-alpha01'` while keeping `implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.1"`