# Android registerForActivityResult not found in

Tags: kotlin, android-activity, android-jetpack

Recently I had updated my dependencies on activity-ktx according to this
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/activity#1.2.0

However, the `registerForActivityResult()` is not found. It is working before this update. Is there anything changes in `androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.2.0`?

[image]

Answer (score 10):

I managed to solved my question. I think I will post my answer here in case it helps for the others.

My solution is to update this dependencies.

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0-beta01'
```

My AS didn't warn me about the update only when I changed the version to `1.3.0`.

PS: I am referring to this [Cannot access 'androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultCaller'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61381545/cannot-access-androidx-activity-result-activityresultcaller)