# Cannot resolve method 'registerForActivityResult'

Tags: android, capacitor

I am building a custom capacitor plugin to fetch the user's phone numbers. I am using capacitor 3 with Ionic 6.

I found a solution which is not deprecated and is a lot recent to fetch the user's phone numbers.

here is my code to get the phone number -

```
private void requestHint() {
        HintRequest hintRequest = new HintRequest.Builder()
                .setPhoneNumberIdentifierSupported(true)
                .build();
        PendingIntent intent = Credentials.getClient(getActivity()).getHintPickerIntent(hintRequest);
        IntentSenderRequest.Builder intentSenderRequest = new IntentSenderRequest.Builder(intent.getIntentSender());
        hintLauncher.launch(intentSenderRequest.build());
    }

ActivityResultLauncher<IntentSenderRequest> hintLauncher = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartIntentSenderForResult(),
            result -> {
                if(result!=null && result.getData()!=null){
                    Intent data = result.getData();
                    Credential credential = data.getParcelableExtra(Credential.EXTRA_KEY);
                    String phoneNum = credential.getId();
                }
            });
```

But I am running across an error on Android Studio "**Cannot resolve method 'registerForActivityResult' in 'NumberPluginPlugin**'"

What am I missing here?
As suggested by some folks online I have added the following dependencies -

```
implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment:1.4.1"
implementation "androidx.activity:activity:1.4.0"
implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$androidxAppCompatVersion"
```

Still I am not sure what is going wrong here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`registerForActivityResult` can be called inside `AppCompatActivity` or `Fragment` (when you are using AndroidX), not some custom `NumberPluginPlugin` class (which doesn't extend the classes mentioned above).

Note that there's no such method in common [`Activity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity), only AndroidX extension of `Activity` brings this feature.

[HERE](https://medium.com/realm/startactivityforresult-is-deprecated-82888d149f5d) you can find some article about how to implement this new way (also with comparison to the old, deprecated one).

Comment: Okay. Where shall I implement this code, a class extending a fragment? or is there any other way?

Comment: yep, in class extending `Activity` or `Fragment`. For fragment you should call it BEFORE `Fragment` attach to `Activity`, e.g. in overriden `onAttach()` method before `super` call

Comment: i'm calling this inside an Activity and STILL getting the error. I have all the androidx dependencies declared in gradle files still issue.

Comment: are you shure you are calling this method inside `Activity` and not inside some inner class? is `this` points on `Activity` on some other class?

Answer (score 3):

try update appcompat to newest version

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `AppCompatActivity` instead of `Activity`

something like :
`public class ActivityMain extends Activity` ----> `public class ActivityMain extends AppCompatActivity`

Answer (score 1):

I resolved my case of "Unresolved reference: registerForActivityResult" by checking the Project Structures->Dependencies->->androidx.activity:activity.
It is caused by using both 1.6.0 and 1.8.0 version that was caused by implementation library further deep in the path.
[image]

After I upgrade the implementation library from github as below such that both activity are now 1.8.x. The issue is resolved.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the `registerForActivityResult` method inside a `Fragment` and still didnt work.
This answer helped me:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66209780/1034622

Answer (score 0):

you may need to add this (if not exist) into your app `build.gradle` :

```
implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.6.0'
```